# How to show all windows on Windows 8 without re-scaling?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, desktop-effects

Upon desktop effects one of the features I appreciate the most is an easy and fast way to show all running windows at once. Like pressing Super-Key on Debian. A variation of this was Flip3D on WIndows 7... Windows 8 has the options of cascading windows, stacking them, and to show them side by side. Unfortunately, these ignore the minimized windows, cover content and/or re-scale the non-minimized sometimes making it difficult to recognize what they are.

Is there a possibility to at once show (and spread) all active windows without re-scaling or modifying their size on Windows 8?

Comment: `Flip3D` or a variation of it still exists in Windows 8+.  Cascading and then selecting side by side effects all windows by the way

Answer (score 0):

may be this is what I am looking for

http://insentient.net/